# Android Studio Build Output Errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am working on Android app, which is in Android Studio.

This is in build.gradle(Module :app) file, which has many dependencies for the project I am working:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cricket.dream11"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.cricket.dream11'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation project(':PGSDKVR4')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'

    //play-services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.4.5'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation project(':cashfreeSDK')
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.loopeer.lib:shadow:0.0.4-beta3'
    implementation("net.orandja.shadowlayout:shadowlayout:1.0.1")
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.5.2'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.7.0'
    implementation ("androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0")

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is in build.gradle(Project: Dream11) file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am trying to run the app in my device. But when running the app, I get this error in "Build Output":

[image]

Can some one please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last screen shot is pretty useless as it simply shows that there were errors but not which. In case of gradle errors always copy the gradle log output (also shown in Android Studio) as text and paste the relevant sections into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your app has three modules :
`app`
`PGSDKVR4`
`cashfreeSDK`
Please check the errors are of which module. Any module in your app which you have decompiled from an existing apk ?

Comment: Not decompiled from existing apk

Comment: can you share me your app code on my mail:  ```vibrant.official275@gmail.com``` so i can check and fix your issue. or i can connect to your pc remotely ?